# Accidentally did a Visual Studio "Update" and lost all my changes. Are they gone forever?

Tags: git, visual-studio, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-mac

I'm using Visual Studio on the Mac and am new to Git.

It seems that after making a lot of changes to my code, that I lost everything I did this morning after doing an "update" (I think, I accidentally clicked on it instead of commit)

Are my changes gone forever? Can I undo this?

I did see Xamarin Studio doing a "stash changes", not sure if that's anything I can see.  There was no warning that I was performing a destructive action... which is why I try to use the GUI since I was hoping that would be there.

[image]

```
MacBook-Pro-1933:zeropki.weboftrust dev$ git reflog
ba0f105 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD
ba0f105 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to ba0f10593d3a60d832dd7576b24f26b2066eb574
6037bdf HEAD@{2}: commit: initial
ca2fa29 HEAD@{3}: commit: Initial check-in of module ZeroPKI.WebOfTrust
25ff84b HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to 25ff84bab87fb6848e00a7a30a7a9fb5ef10e18e
6314e0d HEAD@{5}: commit: initial
3113154 HEAD@{6}: commit (initial): Initial check-in of module ZeroPKI.WebOfTrust
```

Comment: Try to find a `pop stash` or `apply stash` option in your Visual Studio, if there is none you'd need to work with the command-line.

Comment: hopefully there is a way I can list stashes

Comment: Yes there is a way using command line, I don't have experience doing it in visual studio, but this might help you - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/undo?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: nope, no stashes... got to redo everything. probably. le sigh

Comment: what `git reflog` prints in your terminal? This is kinda history of the happenings.

Comment: @gazdagergo updated with that information